# Зачем добавлять в конструктор дочернего класса super(), если компилятор делает это автоматически?

Tags: java, наследование, конструктор

Зачем добавлять в конструктор дочернего класса вызов `super()`, если компилятор делает это автоматически?

Я имею в виду, что в любом случае вначале будет выполнятся конструктор родительского класса и только потом дочернего, зачем же тогда прописывать это вручную?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Потому, что в `super()` вы можете передавать аргументы, в том случае, если вам нужно, чтобы выполнился конструктор с аргументами родительского класса. И от того, аргументы какого типа вы туда передадите, зависит то, какой конструктор выполнится (если их несколько).

Answer (score 9):

Не обязательно в каждом конструкторе вызывать `super()`.

Если базовый класс не содержит конструктора с аргументами, тогда в классах наследниках не обязательно писать `super()`, это подразумевается (эти вызовы расставит компилятор).

Если же у базового класса есть конструктор с аргументами, тогда уже Вам необходимо указать эти аргументы, соответственно необходимо и конструктор базового класса вызвать.

Можно так же передать управление какому-то конструктору из текущего класса, вызвав `this()`, но эта цепочка должна привести к вызову конструктора базового класса, рассмотрите этот пример

```
class Base {
    int i;

    Base(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public class Super extends Base {
    boolean b;
    String s;

    Super(String s, boolean b) {
        this(s);
        this.b = b;
    }

    Super(String s) {
        super(1);
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

Таким образом директивы `this` и `super` позволяют переиспользовать конструкторы и не плодить одинаковый код инициализации